# RealTek wifi adapter disappeared after GPU driver update in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, 20.04, realtek

I updated my GPU driver to nvidia-driver-470 earlier today, but when I rebooted the desktop the BrosTrend AC1LUSB WiFi adapter disappeared. The desktop is a dual boot. I tried booting to Windows and it showed up no problem.

I tried to reinstall the drivers (with an install.sh script), but I got a compile error, and tried to disable and re-enable from Additional Drivers, but I had no luck.

The adapter does show up with `lsusb`, but not with `ifconfig`, and `dkms status` says the driver is 'added' (but not installed?).

Comment: How about sharing those details with us? Please edit your question to add the result of: `lsusb` and also: `sudo dkms status` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Solved in the meantime, added the solution that worked for me to the post 

Answer (score 0):

Removing driver with dkms and reinstall it by following this [instruction manual](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0270/1023/6487/files/AC1L_AC3L_AC5L_Linux_Manual_BrosTrend_WiFi_Adapter_v8.pdf?v=1671154201).

The following instructions (also available at https://linux.brostrend.com) install the appropriate drivers for the AC1L, AC3L and AC5L BrosTrend WiFi adapters in any of the supported distributions. Linux kernels (>= 6.2) include their own drivers for our AC1L/AC3L/AC5L adapters, so they work out of the box in recent distributions, but these drivers aren't yet as mature as ours, so if you encounter any issues, use our installer to replace them.

It's a good idea to fully update and reboot your system with `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade && sudo reboot` before running the installer, as it will avoid a common issue where users have a different running kernel than the installed kernel headers.

Installation steps:

1. Please note that an internet connection is required at the time of installation, in order to be able to download the driver and its dependencies (dkms (`sudo apt install dkms`), linux-headers...). That means that you'll have to use a wired connection (LAN cable) or mobile phone WiFi-to-USB tethering.
2. Insert the WiFi adapter into a USB port.
3. Select all the following line and right-click → copy it to the clipboard: `sh -c 'wget linux.brostrend.com/install -O /tmp/install && sh /tmp/install'`
4. Open a terminal. Right-click → paste the previous command in order to execute it. If it fails with `wget: command not found` please try one of the alternative installation commands.
5. The installer requires root rights, so it will ask for your password. It will then automatically download and install the driver for you. When the installer finishes, the driver should be automatically loaded, but in special cases, a reboot might be necessary.

<sup>**source:** revised from [AC1L AC3L AC5L Linux Manual BrosTrend WiFi Adapter v8](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0270/1023/6487/files/AC1L_AC3L_AC5L_Linux_Manual_BrosTrend_WiFi_Adapter_v8.pdf?v=1671154201)</sup>